# How to optimize this code(Counting Sort)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I was trying to solve classic count sort problem.
my o/p is right, but the time limit exceeded.How can I optimize the below code.
I'm under memory limit.

Time Limit: 5 sec
Source Limit:   50000 Bytes

```
class TurboStart {
    static int integerArray[] = new int[1000001];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException,
            IOException {
        int  i, j;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        j = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        while (j-- > 0) {
            integerArray[Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine())]++;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 1000001; i++) {
            while (integerArray[i]-- > 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be better off on CodeReview.SE

Comment: What input arguments are you passing to TurboStart?

Comment: take a look at here http://ideone.com/KHfN0y

Comment: You might want to check your output loop, too: for frequent values, you are not only accessing the count array, but converting the count to digits over and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `System.out.println` but some smarter way of writing the output([BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)?). Your code for the sort is good so the bottleneck should be the I/O(which is often problem with Java on programming competitions).

Comment: Work like a charm thanks a ton @Ivaylo Strandjev its was I/O problem